# Limit of the a sequence knowing a particular series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Assume $a_n > 0$ $\forall n$ and $\sum a_n$ converges. What is $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n\sqrt{n}$ if this limit exists?
I just need a hint not the full solution.

I tried considering a new sequence $b_n = a_n\sqrt n$. Then taking the limit:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n} = \infty $$ Then the limit must have been of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ so $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n\sqrt{n}= 0$. But I don’t know if this is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n\sqrt{n}\to \gamma >0,$ then $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that

$$ a_n > \frac{\gamma/2}{\sqrt{n}} \qquad \forall n\geq N,\qquad (1)$$

$\implies \sum a_n$ does not converge, a contradiction.

Therefore, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\sqrt{n}$ converges, it must converge to $0,$ and this is possible (I'll leave it to you to come up with examples...)

I will now explain where my inequality $(1)$ comes from. If $a_n\sqrt{n}\to \gamma >0,$ then by definition of limits, given any $\varepsilon>0,\ \exists\ N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lvert a_n\sqrt{n}-\gamma\rvert < \varepsilon\quad \forall n\geq N.$ So, given  $\gamma/2,\ \exists\ N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lvert a_n\sqrt{n}-\gamma\rvert < \gamma/2,$ which implies that $\gamma/2 <a_n\sqrt{n} < 3 \gamma/2\quad \forall\ n\geq N.$ But we only need the $\gamma/2 <a_n\sqrt{n}$ part of this inequality to arrive at $(1).$

Comment: I have a question. Please where did that inequality come from. Because I was thinking if we would use the epsilon-N definition of limit we will rather have the reverse of that inequality. For the example I can set $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: @ChristopherCharles No, if $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ then $a_n\sqrt{n}\not\to \gamma >0.$

My statement starts with, "If $a_n\sqrt{n}\to \gamma >0,$" so this rules out $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ as a possibility. And I have added details about how I arrive at my inequality $(1).$

Comment: Thank you. I understand now

Comment: Happy to help..